# Asp.Net GridView Pager colspan?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

I have a GridView with some data and a pager so that I don't have to display all data on one page.

But if i look at the HTML the GridView generates the pager column has a colspan of 66? This messes up the layout in Chrome and Safari.

Why does it set the colspan to 66 when there are just 5 cols with data?

Edit: I found the problem! I am hiding some columns and those where counted so thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that you can always render the markup as pure CSS using the [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/).

Here you can see an [example with the GridView](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/GridView.aspx)